# Using pointers to calculate the arithmetic mean from string

Tags: c, pointers, strtok

I am struggling with the pointer exercises for my C programming course. I am asked to calculate the arithmetic mean from comma separated list of integers using the prototype `float mean(char *list);` and `strtok` function. However, I can not get my function to work properly. Here is my proposed solution;

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

float mean(char *list);

float mean(char *list) {

    const char sep[] = ",";
    char *token;

    token = strtok(list, sep);
    int8_t value = atoi(token);
    int8_t total = value;
    int8_t count = 1;

    while(token != NULL) {
        token = strtok(NULL, sep);
        value = atoi(token);
        total = total + value;
        count = count + 1;
    }

    double mean;
    mean = total/count;
    return mean;
}
```

Comment: `C` and `C++` are different languages. Tag only the language your code is written in(related to).

Comment: `total = total + value;` total is a **int8_t**. you risk exceeding the capacity of the type **int8_t**

Comment: `strtok/atoi` is much better done with just `strtol`.  `atoi` gives undefined behavior on certain input and ought to be avoided.  `strtok` is destructive and ought also to be avoided.

Comment: When you get the function fixed, try to call it with a string literal (`mean("5,4,10,1")`) to see why using strtok is sub-optimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your while loop, you are updating the token at the start of the loop, so in the next line you should check if the token has become NULL or not - but you are not checking that. Here is the code:

```
float mean(char *list) {
  const char sep[] = ",";
  char *token;

  token = strtok(list, sep);
  int8_t value = atoi(token);
  int8_t total = value;
  int8_t count = 1;

  while(token != NULL) {
    token = strtok(NULL, sep);
    if (token == NULL) break;
    value = atoi(token);
    total = total + value;
    count = count + 1;
  }

  double mean;
  mean = total/count;
  return mean;
}
```

Comment: Adding a check inside the loop is not the idiomatic approach.  The more idiomatic solutions would be to either write a `do/while` loop (incorporating the initial assignment of total) or to write `while( (token=strtok...) != NULL )`.